# Placing markers on geographic map

Tags: geography, geographics

I need to mark some objects in accordance with their coordinates (for example, in the form of blue point). And I found out two ways to realise it:

**Option 1.**

If I have the necessary map (called "EKB") and know the coordinates of image' corners I can somehow to mark the objects. My way is based on some answers I met:

[image]

```
UpperLeftCorner = {FromDMS["58\[Degree]36'01.89''N"], 
   FromDMS["55\[Degree]46'24.20''E"]};
LowerLeftCorner = {FromDMS["55\[Degree]44'59.75''N"], 
   FromDMS["55\[Degree]46'24.20''E"]};
LowerRightCorner = {FromDMS["55\[Degree]44'59.75''N"], 
   FromDMS["66\[Degree]08'20.36''E"]};
UpperRightCorner = {FromDMS["58\[Degree]36'01.89''N"], 
   FromDMS["66\[Degree]08'20.36''E"]};

CoordMapEKB = {UpperLeftCorner, LowerLeftCorner, LowerRightCorner, 
  UpperRightCorner};

Beloyark = {56.842034, 61.319775};
NovoSverdlov = {56.839909, 60.841127};
SredneUralsk = {57.000236, 60.463666};

MaskEKB = 
     Graphics[{Blue, PointSize[Large], Point[GeoPosition[{Beloyark, NovoSverdlov, SredneUralsk}]]}, 
      PlotRange -> Thread[{0, ImageDimensions[EKB]}]];


Show[EKB, Graphics[{Blue, MaskEKB[[1]], MaskEKB[[2]]}]]
```

[image]

As far as I understood, the blue point reflects the position of the necessary object but "in the space of image dimension".

**Option 2.**

It was recommended in comments:

```
GeoListPlot[GeoPosition /@ {Beloyark, NovoSverdlov, SredneUralsk}, 
 GeoRange -> 
  GeoBoundsRegion[{{CoordMapEKB[[2, 1]], 
     CoordMapEKB[[1, 1]]}, {CoordMapEKB[[1, 2]], 
     CoordMapEKB[[3, 2]]}}], PlotMarkers -> Automatic]
```

It really impressed me but what about the image quality? Why it is so bad?

So, **Five questions:**

1. How to mark and note the names of the objects on the *image* knowing the *coordinates*?
2. What is wrong with my code? Do I miss something?
3. Is it possible to mark the objects another way (in both Options)? For instance, using the images:

[image]

4. How to connect these objects by the straight line or polyline (zigzag)?
5. Is it possible somehow to improve the quality in the **Option 2**?

Comment: Hi, please write your code into your post, rather than as images - nobody wants to have to type it out for themselves. You should look at `GeoPosition` and `GeoListPlot` - roughly, something like `GeoListPlot[GeoPosition/@{Bel, Nov, Sred}, GeoRange-> GeoBoundsRegion[...that region...]]` should work.

Comment: The question will be edited in accordance with help center soon. I am sorry for misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, finally I've brought if off by means of provided some help (thanks to [Carl Lange](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/57593/carl-lange)).

What I wanted to get is:

```
EKB = <<Picture of EKB here>>

LowerLeftCorner = {FromDMS["55\[Degree]44'59.75''N"], 
   FromDMS["55\[Degree]46'24.20''E"]};
UpperRightCorner = {FromDMS["58\[Degree]36'01.89''N"], 
   FromDMS["66\[Degree]08'20.36''E"]};

Beloyark1 = {56.842034, 61.319775};
NovoSverdlov1 = {56.839909, 60.841127};
SredneUralsk1 = {57.000236, 60.463666};

GeoGraphics[{Red, PointSize[0.01], 
  Point@GeoPosition[{Beloyark1, NovoSverdlov1, SredneUralsk1}], Thick,
   Dashed, GeoPath[{Beloyark1, SredneUralsk1, NovoSverdlov1}]}, 
 GeoBackground -> GeoStyling[{"Image", EKB}], 
 GeoRange -> Transpose@{LowerLeftCorner, UpperRightCorner}]
```

[image: what I need]

Now it is Ok because in this case I can use necessary map (special one of high quality).

Moreover, I almost managed to use another objects instead of *Red Point* but, from my point of view, it is related to another topic.

Unfortunately, I couldn't increase the quality of the map given WM but, anyway, my main problem is solved.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend reading the documentation for the Geo* functions, since it seems like you may not be aware of a lot of the useful built-ins for this. I hope this helps as a starting point for you to learn about `GeoGraphics` and so on - there's a lot of powerful functionality available there.

To begin with, I've simplified your starting code:

```
bounds = GeoBoundingBox[{GeoPosition@{"58\[Degree]36'01.89''N", 
     "55\[Degree]46'24.20''E"}, 
   GeoPosition@{"55\[Degree]44'59.75''N", "66\[Degree]08'20.36''E"}}]

beloyark = GeoPosition[{56.842034, 61.319775}];
novoSverdlov = GeoPosition[{56.839909, 60.841127}];
sredneUralsk = GeoPosition[{57.000236, 60.463666}];
```

`GeoPosition` is able to take DMS coordinates directly. Furthermore you don't need all four corners - only two opposing corners, and then you can use `GeoBoundingBox`. It's not actually clear to me that you really definitely want to use this bounding box, since your three points are all quite close together at that scale.

Anyways, now that we have those points, we can draw the bounding box simply, just to make sure we got it right:

```
GeoGraphics@GeoBoundsRegion@bounds
```

[image]

Now, we can draw your points, with a line between each of them (using `Line`:

```
GeoGraphics[
 {{Thick, Red, Line@{beloyark, novoSverdlov, sredneUralsk}},
  Point@beloyark,
  Point@novoSverdlov,
  Point@sredneUralsk}, GeoRange -> bounds, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Above, we use `GeoRange -> bounds` because that's what you asked for, but personally I think using the `Automatic` setting is better:

[image]

Finally, let's add some images and labels, as you requested. Above, I used `Point`, but now we'll use `GeoMarker` to add more interesting markers. Because your images aren't separated, I just used example images, but you can replace them with any image you like.

```
GeoGraphics[
 {{Thick, Red, Line@{beloyark, novoSverdlov, sredneUralsk}},
  {GeoMarker[beloyark, ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Boat"}]],
   GeoMarker[beloyark, "Beloyark", "Alignment" -> Bottom, 
    "Scale" -> Scaled@.4, "Color" -> Blue]},
  {GeoMarker[novoSverdlov, ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}]],
   GeoMarker[novoSverdlov, "Novo Sverdlov", "Alignment" -> Bottom, 
    "Scale" -> Scaled@.4, "Color" -> Blue]},
  {GeoMarker[sredneUralsk, ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Airplane"}]],
   GeoMarker[sredneUralsk, "Sredne Uralsk", "Alignment" -> Bottom, 
    "Scale" -> Scaled@.4, "Color" -> Blue]}},
 GeoRangePadding -> Quantity[5, "Kilometers"],
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Finally, here it is with the original bounds you specify (which, again, is too large in my opinion):

[image]

Comment: It is really useful, thanks! But my **main** idea is to make the map of high quality and export it after (and print for educational purposes). Unfortunately, I do not know how to export the image representing the map. Something like `Export["map.png", %, ImageResolution -> 900]` does not work properly. That is why my idea was to upload the high resolution map and work with it. And, as you have already mentioned correct - the marker of the objects turned out too large

Comment: I didn't see that in your original question, sorry. Consider looking at RasterResolution, and also increasing `GeoZoomLevel`. You can also make the marker images smaller by modifying the `"Scale"` parameter.

Comment: Yes, it is my bad. Perhaps, I wasn't quite specific, sorry. Anyway, I'll try do something with your recommendations. But, I think it is worth mention that another reason why I decided to work with **my image** (not with WM geomap) is that my image better fits to my purposes (I don't like the GeoSource used in WM, though it can be fixed any way to fit the needs, I guess). And, also, in this case, I can upload the image which already has high quality. At the first blush, it seemed to me that it would simpler than working with WM GeoMap. Anyway, thanks a lot for your recommendations and help.

Comment: @vladpopovcev Aha, it becomes clearer now. Another option is to use something like `GeoGraphics[{bounds, GeoStyling["GeoImage", yourImage]}]` to project your exact image, and then use your points as above.

Comment: Wow, `GeoStyling` gives a lot! It works, thanks! But the given result is the WM GeoMap of the **bad quality** within the necessary limits and, as I mentioned before, it doesn't fit to educational purposes (especially printing). Hope, I express myself in an understandable way ._.