# The specific GeoMarker from DataSet

Tags: dataset, geographics

With reference to [this related topic](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/192478/placing-markers-on-geographic-map), I have a map (called EKB):

`EKB=`[image: EKB]

The coordinates of the map corners:

```
LowerLeftCorner = {FromDMS["55°44'59.75''N"], FromDMS["55°46'24.20''E"]};
UpperRightCorner = {FromDMS["58°36'01.89''N"], FromDMS["66°08'20.36''E"]};
```

The legends for objects:

```
a1=
```

[image: aes]

```
a2=
```

[image: tec]

```
a3=
```

[image: gres]

I decided to create a dataset at first in order to store the names of the objects and their coordinates.

The dataset:

```
DataSetEkb = Dataset[{
   <|"Names of Objects" -> "Белоярская АЭС", 
    "Coordinates" -> {56.842034, 61.319775}, "Legend" -> a1 |>,
   <|"Names of Objects" -> "Ново-Свердловская ТЭЦ", 
    "Coordinates" -> {56.839909, 60.841127}, "Legend" -> a2 |>,
   <|"Names of Objects" -> "Среднеуральская ГРЭС", 
    "Coordinates" -> {57.000236, 60.463666}, "Legend" -> a3|>}];
```

And finally I got this:

```
GeoGraphics[{GeoMarker[GeoPosition[Normal[DataSetEkb[All, 2]]], 
   Normal[DataSetEkb[All, 3]], "Scale" -> Scaled[0.5]]},
 GeoBackground -> GeoStyling[{"Image", EKB}],
 GeoRange -> Transpose@{LowerLeftCorner, UpperRightCorner}]
```

[image: final]

**Questions:**

1. Why did I get this result and how can it be fixed (what's wrong with my parameters of *GeoMarker*)?
2. Is it okay to use the *DataSet* in such type of the *"task"* (in order to store the objects and their parameters)? What if the number of the objects is more than 2000? Perhaps, there is a better way to store the objects?

(I hope I was sufficiently specific)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd suggest that you first carefully read the document page of `GeoMarker` as it clearly does not specify a syntax where you can use multiple markers for multiple coordinates. So, you have to resort to using multiple `GeoMarker`s instead.

Something like:

```
GeoGraphics[
  {
    GeoMarker[##, "Scale" -> Scaled[0.05]] & @@@ 
      Values@Normal@DataSetEkb[All, {"Coordinates", "Legend"}
  }, 
  GeoBackground -> GeoStyling[{"Image", EKB}], 
  GeoRange -> Transpose@{LowerLeftCorner, UpperRightCorner}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]